# Need help in removing the error 'Duplicate Ids in list'

Tags: trigger

**Scenario :** I have 4 objects **'Proposal(Parent)(Nickname - Group)'** and **'Proposal Line Item(Child)(Nickname - Part)'** , **'Product(it is a lookup field on Proposal Line Item)'** , **'Price List(it has lookup field on both Proposal and Proposal Line Item objects)'**.

Basically the uniqueness of  a **'Proposal Line Item'** record in a **GROUP** depends upon combination of 2 fields **Proposal/Product**. Across the different **GROUPS** it depends on **'Price List'** also.

If a **PART** exist in one **GROUP** with the combination of above two fields and with the same combination another **PART** has to be made in another **GROUP** , then the status of few fields have to change in the **PART** of the first **GROUP**. It should also have the information saying that the **'Part has been moved to another group with its name'**.

I have written a trigger on **'Proposal Line Item'** so that whenever a new record is inserted then it should search for the same combination in the other **GROUPS** and update it if it exists.

Now I have **2 GROUPS**. In **1st GROUP** I have **1 PART** and **2nd** one does not have any. In **2nd GROUP** I am trying to create a **PART** with the same combination as in the **1st GROUP**. Now the fields in the **PART of 1st GROUP** should get updated with the name of new **PART of 2nd GROUP**. But on doing this I am receiving the error `'Duplicate ids in the list on line 728'` I had checked in the debug log and even though I have only one similar record still it is extracting 8 records of same id and putting it in the list which is why the issue is happening.

Below is the code.

**Trigger**

```
Trigger APTPS_ProposalLineItemTrigger on Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c (before insert,after insert) {
    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)) {
        APTS_ProposalLineItemTriggerHandler.UpdateOldNegoGroup(trigger.new);
    }
}
```

**Trigger Handler**

```
Public Class APTS_ProposalLineItemTriggerHandler {
    Public Static Void UpdateOldNegoGroup(List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> ProposalLineItems)
    {
        Set<ID> ProductId = New Set<ID>();
        Set<ID> PriceListId = New Set<ID>();
        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> PLIToUpdate = New List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c>();

        FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI : ProposalLineItems)
        {
            ProductId.Add(PLI.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c);
            PriceListId.Add(PLI.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c);
        }
        System.debug('---ProductId---'+ProductId+' '+ProductId.size());
        System.debug('---PriceListId---'+PriceListId+' '+PriceListId.size()); 

        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> APLIList = [Select  Id, Moved__c , APTS_Expired__c, APTS_Alert_Type__c,
            APTS_Action_Notes__c, APTS_Include__c, Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c, Negotiation_Status__c, Publishing_Status__c,
            XAE_Action_3__c, Apttus_Proposal__Product__c, Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c FROM Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c 
            WHERE Apttus_Proposal__Product__c =: ProductId AND Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c =: PriceListId AND ID NOT IN :ProposalLineItems];
        System.debug('---APLIListSize---'+APLIList.Size()); //Here size is returning 8 even though it should be 1.

            FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI1 : APLIList)
            {
                FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI2 : ProposalLineItems)
                {
                    IF((PLI1.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c == PLI2.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c) && (PLI1.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c == PLI2.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c))
                    {
                        Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c APLIU = New Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c();

                        APLIU.Id = PLI1.Id;
                        APLIU.Moved__c = TRUE;               
                        APLIU.APTS_Alert_Type__c = 'Action';
                        APLIU.APTS_Action_Notes__c = 'This Part has been moved under "' + PLI2.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r.Price_Agreement_Name__c + '"';
                        APLIU.APTS_Include__c = FALSE;
                        APLIU.XAE_Action_3__c = '';
                        PLIToUpdate.Add(APLIU);
                        System.debug('---PLIToUpdate---'+PLIToUpdate);
                    }
                }
            }
        Update PLIToUpdate;  //This is line 728 where duplicate error is thrown.
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Set to remove duplicates. Did you face any issue?

Comment: @TusharSharma I am receiving duplicates in the list 'PLItoUpdate' . I was converting it to set. But I was unable to perform DML on it.

Comment: After assign it to set,clear the list,  assign data back to list and do DML

Comment: @TusharSharma : For assigning back to set I will again have to do a SQL or FOR loop for this ? Or is there any direct way to do this ? As of now my issue is solved with the MAP as suggested by Ashwani but I would like to know this for future developments.

Comment: just add them in list again using `list.addAll(set)`

Comment: @TusharSharma : Ok...Thank you so much. I'll try this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why there are chances of duplicate ID?**

Because you are iterating parent and its child in for of for loop. There are chances that two child have common parent.

**You can resolve this using `Map`:-**

Declare a `Map` instead of `List` to prevent such behavior like:

```
            Map<Id,Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> PLIToUpdate = New Map<Id,Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c>();

            FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI1 : APLIList)
            {
                FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI2 : ProposalLineItems)
                {
                    IF((PLI1.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c == PLI2.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c) && (PLI1.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c == PLI2.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c))
                    {
                        Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c APLIU = New Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c();

                        APLIU.Id = PLI1.Id;
                        APLIU.Moved__c = TRUE;               
                        APLIU.APTS_Alert_Type__c = 'Action';
                        APLIU.APTS_Action_Notes__c = 'This Part has been moved under "' + PLI2.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r.Price_Agreement_Name__c + '"';
                        APLIU.APTS_Include__c = FALSE;
                        APLIU.XAE_Action_3__c = '';
                        // Overwrite old instance
                        PLIToUpdate.put(APLIU.Id,APLIU);
                        System.debug('---PLIToUpdate---'+PLIToUpdate);
                    }
                }
            }
           // Get all values from Map and perform DML
           Update PLIToUpdate.values();
```

**Note:** We should always avoid nested `for` loops  where possible by using collections.

Comment: And a double `for` loop is really the right way? Hmm...

Comment: Not the right way, there can be better use of collection. However, question is not about this. :) Still it will require two `for` loops but, not nested. @AdrianLarson

Comment: Ah but the problem is that now you've posted code that contains that pattern. If you're going to try to help fix the code, copying their code and not fixing mistakes like that is basically tacit support.

Comment: I agree, it is tacit but, a minimum viable solution in context of question would be provided until further question is not asked. We both can see many additional optimization scopes. @AdrianLarson

Comment: @Ashwani : Your solution solves my issue. I am eager to know how can I optimize my code here. It might seem silly at my end but I am not very comfortable with MAPS. I face these kinds of scenario's many times where I have to do nested FOR loop and I want to avoid those in my code. Can you help me in this code to do optimization or provide me any link which I can refer for this ?